# confirmation on how Incite Rampage works on the Gnoll pack lord

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

"Multiattack. The gnoll makes two attacks, either with its glaive
or its longbow, and uses its Incite Rampage if it can."(Monster Manual 163)

I take that to mean that Incite rampage can replace one of the two attacks; The same way shove or grapple does

Looking to confirm that incite rampage is not a free action on a recharge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look closely at the wording of the Gnoll Lord's Multiattack ability, you can see that it can use Incite Rampage as well as its 2 attacks.

> ***Multiattack.*** The gnoll makes two attacks, either with its glaive or its longbow, **and** uses its Incite Rampage if it can.

As it says, 2 attacks **AND** Incite Rampage.

Note that this isn't a "free action" - there's no such thing as a free action in D&D 5e. Incite Rampage is one of the Gnoll Lord's actions, just like Bite, Glaive, Longbow, or Multiattack. The reason it can be performed along with the 2 attacks is because a Multiattack is a single action that allows a monster to do everything it lists.